# Trying to get PHP to send email

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to get PHP to send an email to my email account but it's giving me this error:

http://gyazo.com/5e7870a814be520f2ba2dec32627c7e5

[image]

This is my code on `contact_me.php`

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if( empty($_POST['name'])    ||
    empty($_POST['email'])   ||
    empty($_POST['phone'])   ||
    empty($_POST['message']) ||
    !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
) {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed ???

Comment: on what platform you are working?

Comment: side note *No arguments Provided!* is not a good error message. Additionally that will be triggered if even one field is empty, the error message suggests that *everything* is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu, you need to configure the sendmail or postfix to send emails.

Configure the postix by using the following link : http://crazybrainz.in/configauration-of-postfix-for-mail-sending-through-php-and-magento/

provide some more information to solve your problem.